# How can I make another proposal after the merchant reject the offer?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After I press <kbd>T</kbd> for trade in the trading Depot, and the merchant reject the offer. How can I do to make another proposal?
Or you only can do 1 proposal?

Comment: Piedra libre! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Trading in Drawf-Fortress

Before you can begin trading, your fortress's representative trader must be at the trade depot. Select the trade depot with <kbd>q</kbd> and then request the trader. Be sure that <kbd>b</kbd> reads "Only broker may trade" if you want your broker to represent your fortress. If it reads "Anyone can trade", a random, probably unskilled dwarf will volunteer to conduct the trade. Pressing <kbd>b</kbd> will toggle this setting.

Once your trader has arrived, select the depot again with <kbd>q</kbd> and enter the trade menu. In the trade menu select the items to offer from the right and the desired items from the left. All caravans have a weight limit which cannot be exceeded, and the allowed additional weight is displayed in the lower right corner. If your broker (specifically, not necessarily your trader) has at least Novice or better Appraisal skill, the value of all items will be displayed.

Once the proposal is ready, press <kbd>t</kbd> to propose the trade, but merchants will not agree unless they make adequate profit. Be sure to use trade, not offer <kbd>o</kbd>, as this will make a gift of the selected items. The amount of acceptable profit is determined by the trader's skills and the merchant's mood, described below. Merchants may attempt to propose counteroffers if they do not accept the proposal, which can then be accepted, rejected, or further amended by the trader.

Once a transaction is completed you can start this process again (<kbd>q</kbd> the Depot, go to the trade menu, select items and <kbd>t</kbd>rade), so yes, you can make several small trades with the same merchant.

If you make several offers insultingly low in a row you might offend this merchant and then they will leave without trading anything else (this is when the <kbd>t</kbd>rade option is disabled).

---

Source: [Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Trading)

Comment: Early on, "adequate profit" generally means your offer has to be worth 50% more than what you want from them.

Comment: AS @Fnord23 says in the comments of his answer, sometimes when the offer its very bad, the t command is grayed out. And you can't make another offer.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, I always make a dozen sacrifice trades with a merchant at the beginning of trading to put him in a good mood. Trading him two crossbow bolts for his one crossbow bolt, or two blocks of stone for his one block a bunch of times puts him in a very happy mood. Afterward, I don't have to worry about him getting mad when I trade him my entire inventory for all his stuff at a 25% profit to him.

Even if the merchant likes the profit of specific trade, he will still reject that trade if it will overload his caravan. So keep an eye on the total weight of the items you trading vs. the caravan's weight limit. I believe the merchant uses a different response when he rejects a 'too much weight trade'; something like "I don't see how you can trade all of those items."

Answer (score -3):

You can't. Better take it seriously next time, and increase the profit margin of the traders.

Comment: This seems distinctly wrong; usually they counter with their desired margin, but I don't see how a reject would prevent a trade from happening.  Would you happen to have a source for this?

Comment: Well, there's [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5504/what-determines-the-minimum-profit-a-trader-demands) question, where the same thing happened to someone else. Also, I had it happen to me, today. Merchant refused my offer with something along the lines of: 'I don't see how all those goods will trade', I upped my offer a few times, then he told me to take it seriously next time. After that, the `t`-command to initiate a trade was grayed out. Maybe you could have a source to refute my statement?

Comment: Oh, the [dwarffortress wiki page on trading](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Trading), mentions several times that a trade can be rejected. It does not offer many details though, what this would actually look like in-game, nor how a new trade could be started again..

Comment: What happened was that your initial offer was insultingly low, and after four attempts it still wasn't even within the viability bracket, at which point the trader decided you weren't going to make a serious offer and packed it in.

Comment: If you offer them a really terrible offer, they get annoyed and refuse to trade with you. That's how.